# chequear nombre y usuario y mostrar si estan en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de verificar en la base de datos donde tengo la tabla usuarios, y dentro tengo los campos usuario y nombre, quiero verificar si están los dos y me salga un aviso si ya están o no, en el siguiente código que verifica si el usuario esta en la base de datos, hasta ahí todo bien, cuando quiero agregarle que también verifique por nombre me aparece error, que es lo que estaría faltando, MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU VALIOSO TIEMPO.

Este es el mensaje de error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 12 Fatal error:
> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
> number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php:16 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php(16):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 16

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chequear Usuario y Nombre</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
      {    
     $("#nombre").keyup(function()
      {  
     var nombre = $(this).val(); 
     
      if(nombre.length > 3)
        {  
        $("#result").html('checking...');
     
       $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'chequear.php',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function(data)
        {
        $("#result").html(data);
        }
         });
        return false;
     }
            else
         {
         $("#result").html('');
          }
           });
          });
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="reg-form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
     <fieldset>
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" />
           <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
           <span id="result"></span>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

chequear.php  (aquí es donde creo que tengo el problema porque no me toma el array)

```php
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="baseur2";
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);
if($_POST) 
{
  $usuario = strip_tags($_POST['usuario']);
  $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario 
  ANDnombre=:nombre");
  $stmt->execute(array(':usuario'=>$usuario));
  $stmt->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre));
  $count=$stmt->rowCount();
    if($count>0)
    {
    echo "<span style='color:brown;'>Usuario y nombre ya están en la base 
    de datos !!!</span>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Disponible</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

ajax.js

```javascript
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url  : 'chequear.php',
data : $(this).serialize(),
success : function(data)
{
   $("#result").html(data);
}
});

$.post("chequear.php", $("#reg-form").serialize())
.done(function(data){
$("#result").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Sé que no responde la pregunta, pero por seguridad no se deberían guardar datos sensibles en la base de datos. Quizá el usuario se pueda almacenar directamente, pero nunca la contraseña tal cual. En su lugar se guarda el hash de la contraseña.

Comment: tenes razon, pero esto es para solamente local...gracias

Comment: Veo un error de sintaxis ``ANDnombre``, prueba corrigiendo eso.

Comment: correji el ANDnombre y me sigue apareciendo esto:   Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php(16): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que te falta un parametro en el post

```
<?php
if($_POST) 
?>
```

debe ir con una variable la cual debe estar definida entes de ejecutar dicha sentencia.

```php
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="baseur2";
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);

  $usuario = strip_tags($_POST['usuario']);
  $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);

if($_POST['usuario']) 
{

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario 
  AND nombre=:nombre");
  $stmt->execute(array(':usuario'=>$usuario));
  $stmt->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre));
  $count=$stmt->rowCount();
    if($count>0)
    {
    echo "<span style='color:brown;'>Usuario y nombre ya están en la base 
    de datos !!!</span>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Disponible</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: me aparece esto ahora...Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 8

Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 11

Comment: en tu ajax remplaza por ``data : $("#reg-form").serialize(),`` el serialize() solo estaba tomado un solo parametro.

Comment: me sigue con el error Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuariocheck\otro\chequear.php on line 8

Comment: linea 8 tengo  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

Comment: linea 11tengo  if($_POST['usuario'])  donde me da los errores

Comment: reemplazalo en el index.php, ahí tienes el código, tienes un archivo ajax.js, pero no interviene en el proceso, ya que tienes una rutina en js en tu index.php

Comment: lo cambie tambien en index y me sigue con los errores linea 8 y linea 11, puse en el index el archivo ajax.js que no estaba agregado al head y nada.... no se que es lo que pasa.